# Приложения Android, при упаковке в dex-файл, имеют жёсткое ограничение

Tags: android

Приложения Android, при упаковке в dex-файл, имеют жёсткое ограничение в 65536 ссылочных методов. что это означаем?  и как узнать сколько у меня ссылочных методов?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- > что это означаем?

это означает `Dalvik 65K methods limit:`

*Вы можете ссылаться на очень большое число методов в DEX файле, но вызывать можете только первые 65536, потому что это вся память, которая у вас есть для инструкции вызова метода.
[...] ограничено число методов на которые вы можете сослаться, а не число определенных вами методов. Другими словами, если ваш DEX файл содержит всего несколько методов, но вместе они вызывают 70 000 различных внешне-определенных методов — вы превысите лимит.*

- > и как узнать сколько у меня ссылочных методов?

как вариант с помощью [dex-method-counts](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts)

---

[source](http://habrahabr.ru/post/230665/)